# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException | JNDI lookup

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets

I found lot of questions and answers on this site relating to the addressed problem but could not find solution to my problem so finally had to post this same question again!

I am creating a simple servlet **`DBCPDataSourceExample`**, and getting a connection from **`DataSource`** properties of  which I have provided in `server.xml` & `context.xml` of ***Apache Tomcat v8*** application server.

Below is the **`DBCPDataSourceExample`** servlet:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DBCPDataSourceExample extends HttpServlet  {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respone) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Context ctx ;
    try {
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            Context ic= (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource dts = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/harsh");
            connection = dts.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from stories");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
         while (resultSet.next()) {
             System.out.println("storyId: " + resultSet.getString("storyId"));
             System.out.println("storyTitle: " + resultSet.getString("storyTitle"));
         }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
}
```

**`server.xml`** `Resource` mapping :

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
          global="jdbc/MyDB" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/storyBoard" 
          username="root" 
          password="" 

          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="20" 
          minIdle="5" 
          maxWait="10000"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

**`context.xml`** `Resource` mapping:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/harsh" global="jdbc/MyDB" auth="container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

If there is something wrong with `xml` code I am unable to spot. Please help!

Here is the stack trace from console:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/harsh] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
at com.dbcp.DBCPDataSourceExample.doGet(DBCPDataSourceExample.java:31)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code line where the stacktrace points to is this:

```
                DataSource dts = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/harsh");
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: I hv added stack trace. Please check.

Comment: did you try changing "jdbc/harsh" to this "jdbc/MyDB"

Comment: your lookup should be "jdbc/MyDB" instead of "jdbc/harsh".

Comment: Yes I just tried changing to "jdbc/MyDB". But same error with "jdbc/MyDB"

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki try restarting the server

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki Try restarting your application

Comment: @BilboBaggins yes did that.. but still the same error!

Answer (score 1):

We add resources in server.xml in the mean time we need to create a resource link that's where context.xml is necessary.

In our case, we keep the context.xml in META-INF of our war and sample entry looks like

`<ResourceLink name="email.host.name" global="email.host.name" type="java.lang.String"/>`

Please validate your context.xml entry.

Also make sure you have placed the mysql driver in tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: Well I did put `context.xml` in META-INF folder of my application. Now the error is : 
`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'`
at line : 
`connection = dts.getConnection();`

Now I guess it is asking  for connection details which are in server.xml

Comment: Your context.xml contains entry like below,
`<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="db.url" global="db.url" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>`

Comment: Yes. I can provide connection properties in context.xml and that should work. But my question is how can I access properties defined in server.xml from here if I don't want to provide those properties in context.xml?

Comment: As if I implement Connection pooling and provide the no. of connections (20) detail in context.xml then there will be as much connections for each application (20*no. of apps) as I mention in context.xml. While providing in server.xml will make those available for all applications (20 connections overall)

Comment: context.xml does not have any values to the property, it is just a resource lin k to access the property in server.xml. It is bridge to connect your application and server.xml resources. If you see my comment, the resource link just says the global resource name and its type. Refer this: [link] http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-for-servlet-web-application. I am talking abt point 3 not point 2.

Answer (score 0):

In your Server.xml file i think you need to provide port number in url. 
for example url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storyBoard"

Comment: I tried and got this error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'`

Comment: Make sure that you have added jdbc Drivers with your project